# Java: Converting letters to digits on a phone keypad

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, logical-operators

I'm working on an assignment for a class in which I need to convert a user input of a letter into the number on a phone. Like `A=2` or `K=5`. I converted the user input into Uppercase then into ASCII. I'm using the ASCII for my if/else and it compiles and works but always prints

```
System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 2);
```

no matter what letter I input, also the final line

```
else System.err.println("invalid char " + x);
```

doesn't work, it just prints out the digit is `2` with `x` being the thing I enter.

```
public class Phone {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Please enter a letter from A-Z.");
        char x = input.next().charAt(0);
        x = Character.toUpperCase(x);
        int y = x;
        System.out.println ("You entered the letter " + x);

        if (y>=65 || y<=67)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 2);
        else if (y>=68 || y<=70)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 3);
        else if (y>=71 || y<=73)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 4);
        else if (y>=74 || y<=76)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 5);
        else if (y>=77 || y<=79)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 6);
        else if (y>=80 || y<=83)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 7);
        else if (y>=84 || y<=86)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 8);
        else if (y>=87 || y<=90)
            System.out.println (x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 9);
        else System.err.println("invalid char " + x);           
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is not an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Replace || with && in your if else statements.

Answer (score 1):

On your if-block, your first condition is `if (y>=65 || y<=67)`. Let's open it up a little:

`IF ( y >= 65 ) OR ( y <= 67 )`.

Do you see the issue? Since you've written an OR, the whole statement will always evaluate to `true`: for any int y, y is necessarily either greater than 65 or less than 67. I suspect you meant to write an AND (`&&`).

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong conditions, change `||` to `&&`:

```
if (y>=65 && y<=67) ...
```

And correct all conditions like that.

Having example `(y>=65 || y<=67)`. It means that the condition is `true` always, because any `y` is always larger or equal then 65 **or** smaler or equal than 67 (hard to explain). If you want to check, if both of conditions are true at once, you have to use `&&`

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is `if (y>=65 || y<=67)` and for any character if any of these 2 conditions is satisfied, it will print `x+"'s corrosponding digit is " + 2` and never check any of the other `else if` conditions. You need to replace `||` operator with `&&` operator in all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
char x = input.next().charAt(0);
x = Character.toUpperCase(x);
int digit = 0;
switch (x ) {
   case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
      digit = 1;
      break;
   case 'D': case'E': case 'F':
      digit = 2;
      break;
   //etc.
   default:
      break;
}
if ( digit < 1 ) {
   System.out.println( "The letter " + x + " is not on a phone pad" );
} else {
   System.out.println( "x + "'s corrosponding digit is " + digit);
}
```

Note that some phones may use different letter combinations; for example, some phones use "PQRS" for 7, and some use "PRS", omitting the Q.